# SparkStreaming: class cast exception for SerializedOffset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm writing a custom Spark structured streaming source (using v2 interfaces and Spark 2.3.0) in Java/Scala.

When testing the integration with the Spark offsets/checkpoint, I get the following error:

```
18/06/20 11:58:49 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 58ec2604-3b04-4912-9ba8-c757d930ac05, runId = 5458caee-6ef7-4864-9968-9cb843075458] terminated with error
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.SerializedOffset cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.reader.streaming.Offset
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.flatMap(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

This is my Offset implementation (simplified version, I removed JSON (de) serialization):

```
package mypackage

import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.SerializedOffset
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.reader.streaming.Offset

case class MyOffset(offset: Long) extends Offset {

  override val json = "{\"offset\":"+offset+"}"  

}

private object MyOffset {

  def apply(offset: SerializedOffset): MyOffset = new MyOffset(0L)

}
```

Dou you have any advice about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check that Spark version of your client app is exactly the same as Spark version of your cluster. I used Spark v.2.4.0 dependencies in spark job application, but cluster had Spark engine v.2.3.0. When I downgraded dependencies to v.2.3.0 error has gone.